# How do I specify a filetype in a Google search?

Tags: google-search, search, search-operators

Is there a syntax to specify a filetype in a Google search? What is it? (I'm looking for PDFs.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From Google Help about [Special Search](http://www.google.com/help/faq_filetypes.html#eliminate):

> If you prefer to see a particular set of results without a particular file type included (for example, PDF), simply type “-filetype:pdf” within the search box along with your search term(s).

Actually, the correct syntax is – without the dash:

```
filetype:pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

to search java pdf notes,type the following in google search bar

filetype:pdf java

and you will get all pdf's related to java.
supported values for filetype are pdf,doc,mp3,xml,ppt etc
and don't forget to include ":" between filetype and its value

Answer (score 1):

[https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35287?hl=en#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20filetype,term%20%22galway%22%20in%20them](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35287?hl=en#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20filetype,term%20%22galway%22%20in%20them).

Other have already pointed the pdf, I'm pointing here a more complete article from Google support with all the filetypes available to use with the filetype: operator

```
filetype:
```

It's a small article so I will paste here for everyone, to save your clicking:

> File types indexable by Google
> Google can index the content of most types of pages and files.
> The most common file types we index include:

```
Adobe Portable Document Format (.pdf)
Adobe PostScript (.ps)
Autodesk Design Web Format (.dwf)
Google Earth (.kml, .kmz)
GPS eXchange Format (.gpx)
Hancom Hanword (.hwp)
HTML (.htm, .html, other file extensions)
Microsoft Excel (.xls, .xlsx)
Microsoft PowerPoint (.ppt, .pptx)
Microsoft Word (.doc, .docx)
OpenOffice presentation (.odp)
OpenOffice spreadsheet (.ods)
OpenOffice text (.odt)
Rich Text Format (.rtf)
Scalable Vector Graphics (.svg)
TeX/LaTeX (.tex)
Text (.txt, .text, other file extensions), including source code in common programming languages:
Basic source code (.bas)
C/C++ source code (.c, .cc, .cpp, .cxx, .h, .hpp)
C# source code (.cs)
Java source code (.java)
Perl source code (.pl)
Python source code (.py)
Wireless Markup Language (.wml, .wap)
XML (.xml)
Search by file type
```

You can use the filetype: operator in Google Search to limit results to a specific file type.
For example, `filetype:rtf galway` will search for RTF files with the term "galway" in them.